# EF Core Cosmos DB - Query by partition key returns no data

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

**<EDITED>**
I'm sorry, i forgot to tell that i also have configured conversions in my entity, as follows:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Model.Catalog>()
    .Property(p => p.IdCatalogo)
    .ToJsonProperty("idCatalogo")
    .HasConversion<string>();
modelBuilder.Entity<Model.Catalog>()
    .Property(p => p.Activo)
    .ToJsonProperty("activo")
    .HasConversion<int>();
```

So I understand that with this conversion I can use integer values as PartitionKey, since it is the EF who has the restriction of the data type.

**The model**

```cs
public class Catalog
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Tipo { get; private set; }
    public string Codigo { get; private set; }
    public int IdCatalogo { get; private set; }
    public string SubCodigo { get; private set; }
    public string Nombre { get; private set; }
    public bool Activo { get; private set; }
}
public class Leaf
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public int IdCatalogo { get; set; }
    public string SubCodigo { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

**</EDITED>**

I'm using EF Core for Cosmos DB v7.0.4 whit .Net 7.0 and Azure Cosmos DB emulator.

I have a cosmosdb container to store data about catalogs, something like this:

```json
{
     "id": "5",
     "tipo": "catalogo",
     "idCatalogo": 6,
     "nombre": "Código de Provincia",
     "activo": 1 
},
{
     "id": "22",
     "tipo": "elemento",
     "codigo": "01",
     "idCatalogo": 6,
     "nombre": "Azuay",
     "activo": 1
}
```

The container key is the field `id` and the container partitionkey is the field `idCatalogo`

I need to retrieve all de registries that match with the `idCatalogo` value (in this case 6) and the `tipo` value be the *elemento* word.

I wrote the following lines of code:

```cs
using var ctx = _dbFactory.CreateDbContext();
var result = await ctx.Catalogs.WithPartitionKey("6")
    .Where(c => c.Tipo == "elemento" && c.Activo == true)
    .Select(l=> new Leaf()
    {
        Id = l.Id,
        IdCatalogo = l.IdCatalogo,
        Codigo = l.Codigo,
        Nombre = l.Nombre
    })
    .OrderBy(l => l.Nombre)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();

return result;
```

When the program runs, it doesn't return anything.

```json
{"Result":[]}
```

The SQL query the EF generates is the following:

```
[2023-03-27T21:43:01.780Z] Executing SQL query for container 'Catalogo' in partition '?' [Parameters=[]]
[2023-03-27T21:43:01.781Z] SELECT VALUE {"Id" : c["id"], "IdCatalogo" : c["idCatalogo"], "Codigo" : c["codigo"], "Nombre" : c["nombre"]}
[2023-03-27T21:43:01.782Z] FROM root c
[2023-03-27T21:43:01.783Z] WHERE ((c["tipo"] = "elemento") AND (c["activo"] = 1))
[2023-03-27T21:43:01.784Z] ORDER BY c["nombre"]
```

In the first line we can see a `?` character for the partition value

I configured the container as follow

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Model.Catalog>().HasNoDiscriminator()
    .ToContainer("Catalogo")
    .HasPartitionKey("IdCatalogo")
    .UseETagConcurrency()
    .HasKey(cat => cat.Id);
```

I tried to remove the `WithPartitionKey("6")`  and use `c.IdCatalogo == 6` in the `where` clause but the result is the same.

Also, I tried removing `.HasNoDiscriminator()` from the configuration code but the result is the same.

If I query using Azure Cosmos DB Explorer I obtain the data that I need.

`SELECT * FROM c Where c.idCatalogo = 6 And c.tipo = "elemento"`

Other queries works as expected and I get the data.

I don't find anything in the documentation about query data using partitionkey.

Someone know something about this subject?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite my query as follow:

```cs
var result = await ctx.Set<Catalog>()
    .FromSqlRaw(
        @"Select * From root c Where c[""idCatalogo""] = {0} And c[""tipo""] = {1} And c[""activo""] = {2}", idRoot, "elemento", 1)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
```

And now, I can get the data filtering by partitionkey.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to execute the code posted in question with same sample data, below are my findings for the same:

1. In sample document, `idCatalogo` is saved as datatype *int*, which is **partitionkey** for the documents.

   If its been mentioned while creating *model builder* that container has partition key using `.HasPartitionKey()`. Then while fetching the data using SDK, it is mandatory to pass *partitionKey* with `WithPartitionKey()`. The `WithPartitionKey()` however accepts only string values. Please refer [WithPartitionKey()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.cosmosqueryableextensions.withpartitionkey?view=efcore-7.0)
2. Also, in `where` condition of your .net code you have used `Activo == true`. In sample document, it looks like `activo` value is saved as integer value i.e. *1*. If you use `c.activo = true` in `where` clause of cosmos db  query then you won't be able to fetch any record.

   Hence, your Cosmos Db query is returning you data because you have not used `activo` filter there.

**Changes I made**

We are not allowed to update/change partition key value in Cosmos DB container, so created a new document with `idCatalogo` datatype as *string* as it is the partitionKey.
Below is sample document.

```
{
    "id": "22",
    "idCatalogo": "6",
    "activo": 1,
    "codigo": "01",
    "nombre": "Azuay",
    "tipo": "elemento"
}
```

With the above change when I updated `where` condition for `c.activo == 1` as mentioned below.

```
var result = await context.Catalogs.WithPartitionKey("6")
            .Where(c => c.tipo == "elemento" && c.activo == 1)
```

I am able to fetch the [record/document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi4Ib.png) successfully.

Comment: Hi @RitikaNalwaya thanks for your answer, I edited my question to provide more information about the model, also, if we can see afterward in my question, the SQL instruction that EF generates, it considers the `activo` value as integer.
¿Maybe, the conversions could be the problem? I need that `idCatalogo` use integer values.

Comment: @SirVonJo can you please confirm how you are able to save `idCatalogo` value as *int* in your Cosmos DB collection? When I tried to create a document using posted code I am able to save `idCatalogo` as *string*.

Comment: I'm just reading data from that container I haven't tried to write data yet.